# C# - How to detect browser type

Tags: c#, selenium, browser, detection

I'm running Selenium with C# for my automation testing on multiple browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) and there is one part of my test that passes for Chrome but not Firefox.

Is there a way to detect the browser type that is currently being used during the automated test?

Comment: `((RemoteWebDriver) driver).Capabilities.BrowserName` if not, show what have you tried

Comment: Hi @OscarMartinez: I tried this and Chrome returns the minor version, but IE only returns the major version (11). Do you know how I can get the minor version of IE 11 as well?

Comment: @AngieM are you on Console Application or ASP.NET?

Comment: @OscarMartinez: I have a test project and a unit test utilizing WebDriver. Anyhow, I ended up reading the Registry for IE full version (major + minor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
    + "Type = "                    + browser.Type + "\n"
    + "Name = "                    + browser.Browser + "\n"
    + "Version = "                 + browser.Version + "\n"
    + "Major Version = "           + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
    + "Minor Version = "           + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
    + "Platform = "                + browser.Platform + "\n"
    + "Is Beta = "                 + browser.Beta + "\n"
    + "Is Crawler = "              + browser.Crawler + "\n"
    + "Is AOL = "                  + browser.AOL + "\n"
    + "Is Win16 = "                + browser.Win16 + "\n"
    + "Is Win32 = "                + browser.Win32 + "\n"
    + "Supports Frames = "         + browser.Frames + "\n"
    + "Supports Tables = "         + browser.Tables + "\n"
    + "Supports Cookies = "        + browser.Cookies + "\n"
    + "Supports VBScript = "       + browser.VBScript + "\n"
    + "Supports JavaScript = "     + 
        browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
    + "Supports Java Applets = "   + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
    + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls 
          + "\n"
    + "Supports JavaScript Version = " +
        browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";
```

Comment: How do you get the HttpRequest object in a Selenium test project? The only objects we're dealing with are WebDriver.

Answer (score 2):

You can install UAParser from Nugget :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/UAParser/

It will read the client header and Parse it.

Exemple:

```
  //string uaString = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3";

 // Request the header
  string uaString= HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToString();

// get a parser with the embedded regex patterns
  var uaParser = Parser.GetDefault();

  // get a parser using externally supplied yaml definitions
  // var uaParser = Parser.FromYamlFile(pathToYamlFile);
  // var uaParser = Parser.FromYaml(yamlString);

  ClientInfo c = uaParser.Parse(uaString);

  Console.WriteLine(c.UserAgent.Family); // => "Mobile Safari"
  Console.WriteLine(c.UserAgent.Major);  // => "5"
  Console.WriteLine(c.UserAgent.Minor);  // => "1"

  Console.WriteLine(c.OS.Family);        // => "iOS"
  Console.WriteLine(c.OS.Major);         // => "5"
  Console.WriteLine(c.OS.Minor);         // => "1"

  Console.WriteLine(c.Device.Family);    // => "iPhone"
```